# How to create seperate component just for routes using react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

like the title says I need to create separate component where I will store routes for my project. This is what I have done in App.js component:

```
 <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact />
      <Route path="/messages/messagelist" exact />
      <Route path="/messages/ceostats" exact />
      <Route path="/resourcem/categories" exact />
      <Route path="/resourcem/subcategories" exact />
      <Route path="/resourcem/resources" exact />
      <Route path="/surveys" exact />
      <Route path="/userm/users" exact />
      <Route path="/userm/usergroups" exact />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

What I need to do now, is to extract them for example in separate component let's call it Route.js. How do I do that?

Comment: first create and export your components in another files, then import them into your main file and load with `<Route component={name} />`

Comment: That wasn't my question, but thank you again!

Comment: Oh, I see, an alternative to the given answer, u can simple make a separate component and wrap with the <Switch> component the routes, then u can just add the component to the app.js, right under <Router>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to separate the `RouterProvider` in this way:

First, let create a `RouterProvider.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';


function RouterProvider() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        // Routes 
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default RouterProvider;
```

Now, create a `routes.js` file:

```
import HomePage from 'pages/home';
import AboutUsPage from 'pages/aboutUs';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/home',
    component: HomePage,
    exact: true
  },
  {
    path: '/aboutUs',
    component: AboutUsPage,
    exact: true
  },
 // and so on for other routes in your project
]

export default routes;
```

Back to the `RouterProvder.js` and import the `routes` object and use it:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import routes from 'path/to/routes' // ---> import from routes.js file

function RouterProvider() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        {
          routes.map(route => 
            <Route path={route.path} component={route.component} exact={route.exact} />
          )
        } 
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default RouterProvider;
```

Finally, add the `RouterProvider` as the last layer in the `App.js` file:

```
import RouterProvider from 'path/to/providers/routerProvider'

function App() {
   return (
      <ReduxProvdier>
         <RouterProvider/>
      </ReduxProvider>
   )
}
```

**Note:** `ReduxProvider` is just an example of other providers in your application like `Toast` provider or `Network` provider.

**Note:** creating `routes` object in `routes.js` is not useful in all cases for example if you wanna use `Suspense/Lazy` it's not working as your expectation.

Comment: is not there any way to handle react-router-transition. I wanted to update my routes like you mentioned,but could not handle the transition between components

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I'll take a look at it

Comment: did you try this? https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/animated-transitions

Comment: https://github.com/maisano/react-router-transition this one

Comment: is it possibble to explain how to do it with animated transtion

Comment: I've created a codesandbox with all the things you need, separation on providers and router with the transition. the transition example comes from the official documentation. https://codesandbox.io/s/so-separating-providers-with-router-transition-03mj1  @sayinmehmet47

Comment: Thank you by the way. I have created it with react-transition-group. Because react-router-transition is not working with     "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.8". So I created it here. https://github.com/sayinmehmet47/currency-portfolio. It is working well

Answer (score 1):

```
<Route path="/" component = { ... } exact /> // read docs for more info
```

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component

Comment: The asker appears to be asking about moving the router itself into a component, not how to point their routes at other components.

Comment: Yes, I was asking about what @DBS is saying and the solution was provided, but thank you again!

Comment: Oh, I see, an alternative to the given answer, u can simple make a separate component and wrap with the <Switch> component the routes, then u can just add the component to the app.js, right under <Router>